# tensor product in a k-linear category

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, noncommutative-geometry, triangulated-categories

Studying [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0204218.pdf) i met a "tensor product" construction.At lemma 2.4.1 it is defined an object in D as a direct sum of  $$E[n]\otimes_k H(E[n])$$ I searched on the internet and i found [a comment here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1668060/tensor-product-of-a-vector-space-and-linear-category) that says it is a finite direct sum of $dimH(E[n])$ many copies of $E[n]$.But even with this assumption i have no idea of how to define the canonical natural transformation $\zeta_{1}$ and i was wondering if there is a precise definition of this kind of tensor product which maybe i can deal better with(and of course to define $\zeta_{1}$).I have a basic knowledge on homological algebra and i've never met this notion on  $k$-linear triangulated categories.

> **Remark:** $h_{A_{1}}$ in the paper is a notation for the representable functor $Hom(-,A_{1})$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Rough background on enriched categories:** $\newcommand\V{\mathcal{V}}\newcommand\C{\mathcal{C}}$

Very roughly a $\V$-enriched category is a category $\C$ whose hom-sets have extra structure so that they are objects belonging to another category $\V$, which has a monoidal product bifunctor,
often denoted $\otimes : \V\times \V\to \V$ such that composition of maps can be thought of 
as giving an arrow in $\V$, $$\circ_{X,Y,Z}: \C(Y,Z)\otimes \C(X,Y)\to \C(X,Z).$$

In your case $\V=k\textrm{-}\mathbf{Vect}$, with the usual tensor product,
since all the hom-sets are $k$-vector spaces and composition is bilinear, so the 
composition induces a map $\C(Y,Z)\otimes \C(X,Y)\to \C(X,Z)$, as required.
(Also we'll need $\V$ to be closed monoidal for our purposes, which in the case of vector spaces is just the fact that $\V(V_1,V_2)$ is again a vector space.)

**Tensored categories**

We say that a $\V$-enriched category $\C$ is *tensored* over $\V$ if there is a functor 
(usually also denoted $\otimes$, but for which I'll use $\boxtimes$ for clarity here)
$$\boxtimes : \V\times \C\to \C $$
such that we have a natural isomorphism
$$ \C(v\boxtimes c_1,c_2) \cong \V(v,\C(c_1,c_2)).
$$
In other words, it satisfies a sort of tensor-hom adjunction, and makes $\C$ into a [module category](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/module+category) over $\V$. See the [nlab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/powered+and+copowered+category) for more on tensored categories, although the nlab calls them copowered categories. Now you can see that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3108646/90543) is also related

**The explanation**

As you may have guessed, what's going on here is that we are taking a tensor product in the sense just defined. These are not always guaranteed to exist, but in the special case of vector spaces, we just need coproducts to exist, as the [comment you linked to](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1668060/90543) indicates. We also don't necessarily get all tensor products, so we don't necessarily have a functor as we would like, the construction I'll give only goes through for finite vector spaces in your example.

First let's say what it means for a tensor to exist without the whole functor existing.

We say that an object $y\in \C$ is the tensor of $v\in \V$ with $c_1\in\C$ if
there is a natural isomorphism (in $c_2$)
$$ \C(y,c_2) \cong \V(v,\C(c_1,c_2)).$$
Note that the natural isomorphism is actually part of the definition of $y$. $y$ is then unique up to unique isomorphism if it exists, and I will denote such a $y$ by $v\boxtimes c_1$.

If such objects $y$ exist for all pairs $v$ and $c_1$, then they assemble into the functor $\boxtimes : \V\times \C\to \C$ discussed above.

Now let $\V$ be the category of $k$-vector spaces, and $\C$ be a $k$-linear category (meaning enriched over $\V$) with finite coproducts and a zero object (comes for free with triangulated category, since those are additive).

Then if $v\in\V$ is finite dimensional, $v\boxtimes c$ exists for all objects $c\in\C$.

*Proof*

Take a basis $e_1,\ldots, e_n$ for $v$. Let $y = \bigoplus_{i=1}^n c$, then for any $d\in\C$, 
$$\C(y,d) 
= \C\left(\bigoplus_{i=1}^n c,d\right)
\cong 
\bigoplus_{i=1}^n \C(c,d)
\cong 
\V(v,\C(c,d)).\quad \blacksquare
$$

**What is $\zeta_1$?**

We have 
$$A_1 := \bigoplus_n E[n]\boxtimes H(E[n]),$$
where $H:\C^{\text{op}}
\to\V$ is a contravariant cohomological functor of finite type 
(meaning that $\bigoplus_n H(E[n])$ is finite dimensional for all $E\in\C$).
Fix bases $v_{n,i}$ for $1\le i \le m_n=\dim H(E[n])$, so that 
$$A_1 = \bigoplus_n \bigoplus_{i=1}^{m_n} E[n].$$

We want to show that there is a canonical natural transformation (natural in $F\in\C$)
$$
\C(F,A_1) \to H(F).
$$
Now notice that 
$$
\C(F,A_1)
\cong
\bigoplus_n\bigoplus_{i=1}^{m_n}\C(F,E[n])
\cong 
\bigoplus_n \C(F,E[n])\otimes_k H(E[n])
$$
since the sum is finite. Note that the tensor product is now the usual 
tensor product over $k$.

Then for each $n$, we have a bilinear map $\C(F,E[n])\otimes_k H(E[n])\to H(F)$
defined by $\phi\otimes h \mapsto H(\phi)h$. Together these give the desired map $\zeta_1$.

Observe that $\zeta_1$ is surjective for $F=E[n]$, since we can just observe that 
the image of $\mathrm{id}_{E[n]}\otimes h$ is $h$ for all $h\in H(E[n])$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation.I am a first year graduate student and i feel that homological algebra is a huge,vast field of mathematics.Could you recommend me a good book for enriched categories?It seems that is a fundamental notion.

Comment: @T.Karawolf I'll be honest, I'm also a first year grad student, and I'm mostly familiar with these concepts from my Algebraic Topology class, so you might be better served by asking a new reference-request question on good books for enriched categories. My best guess right now might be to check out Riehl's Categorical Homotopy Theory. Chpater 3 is on the basics of enriched categories.

Comment: Eh actually one more question about the proof.I noticed that you used the isomorphism $C(F,A_{1})\cong \underset{n} {\oplus}C(F,\oplus E[n])$ but this direct sum is infinite.Why is this true? @jgon

Comment: The direct sum (though it looks infinite) is actually finite because of the assumption that $H$ is finite type, meaning that $\bigoplus_n H(E[n])$ is finite dimensional for all $E$.

Comment: oh yes of course i was thinking the property "finite type" was only $dim{H(E[n])}<\infty$ but is something more, $\sum_{n}dim{H(E[n])}<\infty $.Thank you again !!